# Joomla menu items into clickable div's

Tags: joomla-2.5, module, menu

I'm working on customizing the Joomla menu as a little experiment to see how customizable I can make it. However, now that I've made every menu item into an editable button, I've decided to change them from UL/LI to DIV's.

Now, the thing is, I've been using the default  `mod_menu`, and in there you don't really work with `<a href...`  or anything, and so when I turn the li's into div's, it's only the text within the div that is clickable rather than the entire div.

It looks nice, and it almost does what I want it to do, but main priority is that the entire div containing the one article link acts as a button, that I can click to go to that page.

Does anyone have any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, do not remove the `<a>` tag at all as this contains the links `href` and if removed, you will need to resort to something like jQuery.

So assuming for example you have the following markup for a menu:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">About</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently the text is the only clickable thing because the `<a>` tag by default is `display: inline;`

So all you have to do is use the following CSS:

```
.menu .item a {
    display: block;
}
```

This basically extends the element to the full dimensions of it's parent.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of this, haha. I guess it's the monday morning that does that to me! Thanks!